# Error formatting date in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm using Clojure 1.7.0 and ClojureScript 1.7.170. For formatting dates I'm using cljs-time 0.3.14.

The following example in figwheel crash in my machine while it works in another:

```
=> (require 'cljs-time.core 'cljs-time.format)
=> (cljs-time.format/unparse (cljs-time.format/formatter "yyyy") (cljs-time.core/date-time 2010 10 3))
#object[TypeError TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of null]
 clojure.string.replace_with.G__31150__delegate (jar:file:/Users/juanjo/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojurescript/1.7.170/clojurescript-1.7.170.jar!/clojure/string.cljs:37:10)
 clojure.string.replace_with.G__31150 (jar:file:/Users/juanjo/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojurescript/1.7.170/clojurescript-1.7.170.jar!/clojure/string.cljs:33:10)
 clojure.string/replace-all (jar:file:/Users/juanjo/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojurescript/1.7.170/clojurescript-1.7.170.jar!/clojure/string.cljs:29:13)
 Function.clojure$string$replace (jar:file:/Users/juanjo/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojurescript/1.7.170/clojurescript-1.7.170.jar!/clojure/string.cljs:53:8)
 Function.cljs.core.apply.cljs$core$IFn$_invoke$arity$2 (jar:file:/Users/juanjo/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojurescript/1.7.170/clojurescript-1.7.170.jar!/cljs/core.cljs:3448:18)
 cljs.core/apply (jar:file:/Users/juanjo/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojurescript/1.7.170/clojurescript-1.7.170.jar!/cljs/core.cljs:3439:1)
 cljs_time$format$unparse (jar:file:/Users/juanjo/.m2/repository/com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time/0.3.14/cljs-time-0.3.14.jar!/cljs_time/format.cljs:439:4)
```

In the working computer, this is the result:

```
=> (cljs-time.format/unparse (cljs-time.format/formatter "yyyy") (cljs-time.core/date-time 2010 10 3))
"2010"
```

This is the error I'm getting in chrome:

[image]

**Update**

This are my dependencies:

```
 :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
             [selmer "0.9.5"]
             [markdown-clj "0.9.82"]
             [environ "1.0.1"]
             [ring-middleware-format "0.7.0"]
             [metosin/ring-http-response "0.6.5"]
             [bouncer "0.3.3"]
             [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
             [org.webjars/bootstrap "3.3.6"]
             [org.webjars/jquery "2.1.4"]
             [com.taoensso/timbre "4.1.5-SNAPSHOT"]
             [com.taoensso/tower "3.0.2"]
             [compojure "1.4.0"]
             [ring-webjars "0.1.1"]
             [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.5"]
             [ring "1.4.0" :exclusions [ring/ring-jetty-adapter]]
             [mount "0.1.6"]
             [migratus "0.8.8"]
             [conman "0.2.7"]
             [org.postgresql/postgresql "9.4-1203-jdbc41"]
             [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.7.170"]
             [reagent "0.5.1"]
             [reagent-forms "0.5.13"]
             [reagent-utils "0.1.5"]
             [com.domkm/silk "0.1.1"]
             [kibu/pushy "0.3.6"]
             [org.clojure/core.async "0.2.374"]
             [cljs-ajax "0.5.2"]
             [metosin/compojure-api "0.23.1"]
             [metosin/ring-swagger-ui "2.1.3"]
             [org.immutant/web "2.1.1"]
             [com.carouselapps/free-form "0.2.0"]
             [re-frame "0.6.0"]
             [com.andrewmcveigh/cljs-time "0.3.14"]]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce at the moment. Any chance you could post your `project.clj`? Or at least all the dependencies/plugins?

Maybe you could try clearing out the directory: `/Users/juanjo/.m2/repository/com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time/`. The line number of `cljs-time.format/unparse` doesn't quite match up with https://github.com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time/blob/v0.3.14/src/cljs_time/format.cljs#L452 - though that could just be a source mapping thing.

Comment: @AndrewMcveighin in ~/.m2/repository/com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time I have 2 folders, 0.3.0 and 0.3.14
if I delete 0.3.0 and try to run the project again
i get:
Retrieving com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time/0.3.0/cljs-time-0.3.0.pom from clojars

Comment: It's working now after deleting the 2 folders and run lein clean.